Efficient method to isolate open drain output from mcu
I'm using the LTC4418 power path controller

My power sources include a solar panel which can produce voltages close to 30V. I want to send the VALID status outputs to my MCU but it is on a different ground reference than this IC so I am looking at optocouplers.
The most efficient optocoupler I've found has a minimum 300uA forward current, meaning power draw will be 30 x 0.0003 x 2 = 18mW, which I would like to improve on.
I haven't looked closely at a buck converter to drop the voltage before the optocouplers since I gather they have poor efficiency at light load.
Is there a better strategy?

I would consider using two optocouplers:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When "From Processor" is asserted, the lower optocoupler turns on, allowing current to flow from 30V.  If /Valid is pulled down, "To Processor" is also pulled down.
When "From Processor" is low, the lower optocoupler is off.  No current flows from the 30V, so the upper optocoupler is also off and the circuit draws no power.
The processor can check the /Valid signal periodically and at a low duty cycle, at the cost of one extra processor pin. You could easily reduce your average power by a factor of 100 by asserting "From Processor" for 10 milliseconds every second.
